# Using fwrite to display sql query

Tags: php, sql, fwrite

I'm trying to pull a username from a sql database to place on [my chat](http://www.goawaymom.com/). My database is structured as seen below. no matter what I do, It doesn't work which I don't seem to understand because I'm able to echo people's usernames by doing  .$user_info['username']. However when I place it within a fwrite function nothing shows up. 
What am I missing, why isn't the username showing up within the fwrite function.

[db http://goawaymom.com/db.jpg](http://goawaymom.com/db.jpg)

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("root_members") or die(mysql_error());

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$text = $_POST['text']; 
$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'> ".$user_info['username'].">".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."</div>");
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: does nothing show up in the file? or the page

Comment: the username doesn't show up anywhere on the file or page, when it is placed within fwrite.

Comment: where does `$user_info['username']` get defined?

Comment: because it doesn't seem to be defined anywhere...

Comment: How do i properly define it then, because I thought i had defined it within my index.php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define $user_info:

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("root_members") or die(mysql_error());

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){

// select from database
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="' . $_SESSION['name'] . '"'); 
// retrieve row
$user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // fixed this from mysql_fetch_row to mysql_fetch_assoc

$text = $_POST['text']; 
$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'> ".$user_info['username']." &gt;".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."</div>");
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry. try it now. mysql_fetch_row would not work, it needed mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Careful - this script has a vulnerability.  See my answer for one method of escaping your SQL query.  Also, if you don't need the entire row, I recommend pulling `username` only, as it's unnecessarily taxing to pull everything.

Answer (score 2):

Where is `$user_info` being populated?  Looks like that is the missing piece of the puzzle.  I also fixed the greater than symbol, which needs an entity code to render properly in HTML.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("root_members") or die(mysql_error());

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT username FROM root_members WHERE querygoeshere='%s'",
                   mysql_real_escape_string($querygoeshere));

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Could not execute query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $username = $result[0];

    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>" . $username . " &gt; " . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text)) ."</div>");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `fwrite` is fine, but your `>` following the username output is probably getting confused by the browser as the end of the tag.

Try this:

```
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'> ".$user_info['username']."&gt;".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."</div>");
```

Comment: Where is `$user_info['username']` defined? What happens if you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: I see some other answers targeted the missing `$user_info['username']` variable as well. Glad you got it working!